# On rare occasion, <canvas> doesn't redraw

Tags: javascript, canvas, redraw

I use `<canvas>` to draw all notes and glyphs in my music education web apps:
http://www.musictheory.net/exercises/keysig/bc98yy

A Firefox 15.0.1 user has reported that sometimes the exercise goes on to the next question, but the canvas still shows the previous question.  I have seen this occur in testing one time (out of ~500 questions).

When it occurs, the canvas has been cleared via both `canvas.width = canvas.width` and a call to `.clearRect` on the context and glyphs have been drawn in JavaScript via `.beginPath`, `.quadraticCurveTo`, `.closePath`, etc.  However, it seems like the canvas's backing buffer never gets flushed/drawn into the window.

I have seen bug reports in the past regarding similar issues:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787623
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794337
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55339

I can force a redraw by doing a DOM hack such as inserting a text node as a child of the canvas, and then removing it on the next run loop cycle, or modifying the background-color or padding of the canvas.  This seems heavy-handed, however, and I keep having the nagging feeling that I'm missing something obvious.

My drawing code is simple enough:

```
canvas.width = width;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.save();
// Lots of drawing code here
ctx.restore()
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 1); // Helped force a repaint on some older WebKit browsers?
```

I have ensured that the number of `.save` and `.restore` calls are balanced.

1) I am calling this code directly in response to an `onclick` event handler.  Should I instead be using `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` to perform the drawing on a future run loop cycle?

2) I'm not missing something obvious, like a `canvas.pleaseRepaintNow()` API, right?

3) Have other people encountered similar issues and resorted to DOM modification to force redraws?

Answer (score 4):

Add `context.stroke();` to the last line of your `onLoad` function, it fixes a bug in Firefox.  Otherwise changes to the canvas don't render until the window is redrawn.

It worked in my case at least.

```
window.onload = function() {
   canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   //Code here...
   context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Do you know what Firefox versions this affects?  Is there an entry in the Firefox Bugzilla for it?  Thanks!

Comment: It effects version 15, and has been reported [already](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790738). It is interesting that they say the issue occurs for chrome as well, even though it is more up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the bug to happen but after madly clicking in Firefox for awhile, I never saw it.  This is how I clear the canvas which seems to work, but take it with a grain of salt since I can't get the bug to occur I also can't check to see if this fixes anything...

```
// Store the current transformation matrix
ctx.save();

// Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Restore the transform
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Upvoting due to the setTransform(), which I definitely was missing.  The issue remains, however :(

Comment: Do you have a method to make it reliably happen? Or just keep clicking?

Comment: I do not, it only happened on my machine once.  A user can reliably reproduce it within a 100 questions, however (running Firefox 15.0.1 on OS X 10.7 on a 2011 MacBook Pro).  I have tried to match his configuration as close as possible, but with no luck in reproducing.

Comment: Have you considered asking the user to disable all extensions and addons, in case some misbehaving third party code is the culprit?